# Compare FCC structure's DFT band result with ARPES data

Tags: density-functional-theory, band-structure

FCC structure's crystal primitive cell is not cubic.
However, when we use ARPES to measure a FCC crystal, we usually choose a cubic Brillouin zone, and the experiment's path is not the FCC primitive cell's high symmetry path. I try these two way to solve the problem, and meet some problems (we choose $(0,0,0)$-$(0,\pi/a,0)$ as the experiment's path):

1. I build up a cubic unit cell of FCC crystal, and calculate its $(0,0,0)$-$(0,\pi/a,0)$'s path's band.
2. I use primitive cell to do the SCF, then choose $(0,0,0)$-$(b_1+b_3)/2$ as the path to show the band.

For option 1, I think I should unfold the band, but how to choose the primitive cell's path to unfold? I'm not certain of the validity of option 2.

Comment: I think some information is missing, what material are you looking at ?

If ARPES is not measured along the primitive unit cell, it could mean that this is not suited for the material. For instance, if it is magnetic, naturally the unit cell will be "doubled" to allow for the two magnetic sites to appear in the unit cell, then you will see some band folding in the ARPES data.